# python .format() repeated fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know in python3, you can do something like:

```
>>> '{0} {1} {0}'.format(13, 42)
'13 42 13'
```

So you're using the same argument multiple times. I'd like to do the opposite. I have a sequence of numbers. I'd like to somehow print them using a single format specifier, but I don't see a way to indicate to the `format` syntax that a given identifier should consume the next N arguments. I can use a reduce

```
>>> reduce(lambda out,x: out + '{:02X}'.format(x), b'\x60\x0d\x1a\xdd', '')
'600D1ADD'
```

But I was hoping for a single format invocation, as I had some other characters I wanted to place around my otherwise formatted sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any way to do that exactly.  What you could do is pre-format your list of numbers, then pass that formatted string as a single item to a second round of formatting:

```
>>> nums = (13, 42)
>>> '{0} is {1}'.format('my stuff', ''.join('{:02X}'.format(a) for a in nums))
'my stuff is 0D2A'
```

If you wanted, you could write a custom Formatter subclass that accepts a sequence of numbers as a single item to be formatted, and formats them all together.  That could let do something like `myFormatter.format('{0} is {1:list}', 'my stuff', (13, 42))`.  Here's how it could work:

```
class ListFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, spec):
        if spec == 'list':
            return ''.join('{:02X}'.format(a) for a in value)
        else:
            return super(ListFormatter, self).format_field(value, spec)

>>> lf = ListFormatter()
>>> lf.format('{0} is {1:list}', 'my stuff', [1, 43])
'my stuff is 012B'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish it were otherwise. But it's good to know it just don't have that support.

Answer (score 5):

What about just something like this:

`list = [13, 14, 42, 43]`
`out = ''.join([ '{0}'.format(x) for x in list ])`

Answer (score 3):

I've used something along these lines:

```
>>> list = [13, 14, 42, 43]
>>> ('0x' + len (list) * '{:02X}') .format (*list)
'0x0D0E2A2B'
```